# Is there an algorithm to find the splitting field of a polynomial over galois finite fields?

Tags: finite-fields, splitting-field

how can I find the splitting field of polynomial $x^{13}+1$ over $GF(2)$?

Comment: In a sense the degree of the irreducible polynomial tells us what the splitting field is, up to isomorphism.   The hardest part may be checking for irreducibility.

Comment: Notice that $x^{13}+1$ is not irreducible, as $1$ is a root of it over the field with $2$ elements. Or does the $GF(2)$ in your notation have another meaning?

Comment: edited. irreducible is not a part of it... I want to find the field on which $x^{13}+1$ can be reduced to $\prod_i(x-a_i), a _i \in GF(2^m)$

Comment: You can have a look at the [Berlekamp's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlekamp%27s_algorithm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that:

1. Every irreducible polynomial over a finite field is separable
2. The field $GF(p^n)$ is the splitting field of $x^{p^n-1}-1$ over $GF(p)$.

In particular, for any separable polynomial $f(x) \in GF(p)[x]$ you have
$$f(x) \mbox{ splits on } GF(p^n) \Leftrightarrow f(x) \mbox{ divides } x^{p^n-1}-1 $$

So an algorithm to find the splitting field of $f$ would be:

1. start with $n=1$.
2. compute $r(x)=x^{p^n-1}-1 \mod{f(x)}$ with the Euclidean algorithm.
3. if $r(x)=0$, the splitting field is $GF(p^n)$
4. otherwise, raise $n$ of one unity and go to step 2.

For your particular case, $x^{13}+1$ divides $x^{2^n-1}-1$ if and only if $13$ divides $2^n-1$: the smallest such $n$ is $12$ (because of Fermat's little theorem), hence the splitting field of $x^{13}+1$ over $GF(2)$ is $GF(2^{12})$.

Comment: a followup question, what can I say about the multiplicative orders of the roots of the polynomial over the extended field?

Comment: Well, every root of $x^{13}-1$ is a $13$-th root of unity. So, the multiplicative order of all these roots is $13$: these indeed satisfy $x^{13}=1$.

Comment: over the larger field?

Comment: I don't get your last question. The roots do not belong to $GF(2)$: they belong to the larger field.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ P (X) = X ^ n-1 $,  $ \Phi_n$ the n-cyclotomy polynomial over $ \Bbb{Q} $.
 Let $ p $ a prime number and $F_p$ the prime field of
characteristic $ p $ and $ \Phi_ {n , F_p}$ the polynomial $
\Phi_n $ modulo $p$.

Link between $ \Phi_n $ and $ \Phi_ {n,F_p} $ :

Let $ d $ the order of $ p $ in the multiplicative group of
units of the ring $  Z_n$,  then $ \Phi_ {n, F_p} $ is
the product in $F_p[X]$  of $ \frac {\varphi(n)}{d} $ irreducible
factors of degree $d$.

Application:

The splitting field of $ X^{13} + 1 $ on $  F_2$ is the same as
the splitting field of  $ X^{13}  -1$, so according to the above
result knowing about  the order of $p=2$ in $Z_{13}$ that is 12
equal to $\varphi(13)$ that $ \Phi_{n, f_p} = X^{12} +
X^{11}+\cdot\cdot\cdot +X+1 $ is irreducible in $F_2 [X]$, and
like any primitive root of this polynomial generates  all
others root of $ X^{13} + 1$ so, the splitting field is a cyclic
extension of degree 12, is therefore $ F_{2^{12}} $.